# How do I detect if a native dialog is opened?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, dialog, screen

Is there a way to detect if a native dialog is opened in Flutter Framework?

Example of a native dialog below:

[image]

I would like to detect if a native dialog is opened because I use **paused** and **inactive** AppLifeCycle state to change the screen behavior. However, when the native dialog is opened the AppLifeCycle is set to **inactive**.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's native you can't really tell what's in front of your app when it moves to the inactive state, but you could use the [visibility_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector) package to detect if and where a widget is obscured by something.

Comment: it did not work :(